# From Glide.with showing ImageView Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-imageview, android-glide

I am trying to solve this issue but i didn#t find enything until now. So my Image View its a string and i am trying to call it with Glide.with and many more but unfortunately no success until now. It should be a simple Line of code but i am not finding it.

```
class ImageInformation : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_information)



            val image = intent.getParcelableExtra<ImageModel>("image")
            if (image != null){
                val downloadUrl: TextView = findViewById(R.id.downloadUrla)
                val previewUrl : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.previewUrls)
                val id: TextView = findViewById(R.id.idsa)
                val filename: TextView = findViewById(R.id.fileNamea)
                val filesize: TextView = findViewById(R.id.filesizea)
                val contentType: TextView = findViewById(R.id.contentTypea)
                val createdBy: TextView = findViewById(R.id.createdBya)
                val createdTimestamp: TextView = findViewById(R.id.createdTimestampa)
                val creationSource: TextView = findViewById(R.id.creationSourcea)
                val domainIdentityType: TextView = findViewById(R.id.domainIdentityTypea)
                val domainIdentityValue: TextView = findViewById(R.id.domainIdentityValuea)
                val tags: TextView = findViewById(R.id.tagsa)
                val description: TextView = findViewById(R.id.descriptiona)



                    downloadUrl.text = image.downloadUrl

                     

TO DO, Preview URL
                    //previewUrl.setImageResource(image.previewUrl)//Required Int not a String.
                    //Glide.with(this).load( previewUrl).into(previewUrl)
                    //Glide.with(Activity()).load(previewUrl).centerInside().into(previewUrl)
                    //previewUrl.setImageResource(image.previewUrl)
                    //Glide.with(Activity()).load(previewUrl).into(image.previewUrl)          
                    //Glide.with(this).load(previewUrl).centerInside().into(image.previewUrl)
                    //previewUrl.setImageResource(image.previewUrl)

                    //Nothing from the above lines doesn#t work. 


                    id.text = image.id
                    filename.text = image.fileName
                    filesize.text = image.filesize.toString()
                    contentType.text = image.contentType
                    createdBy.text = image.createdBy
                    createdTimestamp.text = image.createdTimestamp
                    creationSource.text = image.creationSource
                    domainIdentityType.text = image.domainIdentityType
                    domainIdentityValue.text = image.domainIdentityValue
                    tags.text = image.tags.toString()
                    description.text = image.description



            }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```kotlin
Glide.with(context)
    .load(image.downloadUrl) // here we are telling Glide what it needs to load
    .into(previewUrl) // here we are telling Glide where to load it into (your imageView)
```

I must say your naming of you ImageView (`previewUrl`) does make it very hard to read, it might be better to rename it to something like `previewImageView`.